# How do I replace missing revenue data using the "IF" function in Excel?

Tags: excel, finance

Adjusted Revenues – If there is a year without a value (blank or zero) of Revenues use an IF function to copy forward the value from the previous year.

Does anyone know what "IF" function I could use for this? In my case, ABB is missing revenue data for 2013 so I have to replace it with 2011 by using the IF function.

[image]

Comment: So are you unclear on how to test if a value is 0 or blank?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a new column in my Data. First sort your data by Company and Year.

Cell D2 Formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,C2=0),C1,C2)
```

This works well unless the First year for that company is 0, as is the case for company ZZZ. Doubt you'll run into that situation, so no worries right? Then create your pivot table after your data are fixed.

[image]